# Proper way of using typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am fairly new to Typescript and have one question about it.

In React, I encountered a situation whereby the state of a component can be undefined or a number. And I have a function that must use that particular state object as argument to dispatch action (let say calling API), and the argument cannot be undefined in order to call the API. Code is below.

```
 interface IState {
   someId?: number;
 }


 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): IPropsFromDispatch => ({
   getSettings: someId => dispatch(getRequest(someId)),
 });

 class someComponent extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  
   public constructor(props: IProps) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       someId: undefined
     };
   }

   public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IProps, prevState: IState) {
     if (this.state.someId !== prevState.someId) {
       this.props.getSettings(this.state.someId);
     }
   }

   public render() {
     return (
       <Dropdown
        handleOnSelect={(e) => {this.setState({someId: e.target.value })} }
       />
     )
   }
 }
```

Basically the someId state initially is undefined, but after selecting through dropdown, it will set the state for someId and trigger the dispatch getSettings action.
If I specify type format of the dispatch,

```
 interface IPropsFromDispatch {
   getSettings(someId: number): void;
 }
```

it will throw me an error saying

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

The error will be gone if I do this of course

```
interface IPropsFromDispatch {
   getSettings(someId?: number): void;
}
```

But I dont think this is recommended in using Typescript, since the dispatch action expects to have the someId as a number, not undefined, to be able to work. Or am I wrong? How should I do this?

Comment: See "typescript type narrowing" in your favourite search engine. Here's a nice result:  https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/chapters/narrowing/#truthiness-narrowing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check that `state.someId` is truthy:

```
 if (this.state.someId && this.state.someId !== prevState.someId) {
   this.props.getSettings(this.state.someId);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What your are looking for are implicit type casts.
Lets refer to the usage of `getSettings`

```js
public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IProps, prevState: IState) {
  if (this.state.someId !== prevState.someId) {
    this.props.getSettings(this.state.someId);
  }
}
```

If you add a null check typescript will implicitly cast `number | undefined` to `number`

```js
public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IProps, prevState: IState) {
  if (this.state.someId && this.state.someId !== prevState.someId) {
    this.props.getSettings(this.state.someId); // someId is now of type number
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I gotta pick one to mark as solution. So I picked the earliest answer that is similar to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set it to `undefined` directly unless the type would be `number | undefined`. Either use `null` as a default value or simply set `this.state = {}` which will result in `state.someId` being `undefined` (since it is not set).

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for the React part but typescript is behaving like expected
You define `someId` as undefined upon initialisation.
Use your second signature and check for the truthyness of the value and it will be casted as a number pass the `if`